# How to select a button from RadioGroup

Tags: android

How to select single item from a RadioGroup. I have shared a sample code. Helps will be appreciated.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/gender"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_edit_text"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/male"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/female"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/female" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RadioGroup gender = findViewById(R.id.updateGender);

if(condition_for_male) {
    gender.check(R.id.male);
} else {
    gender.check(R.id.female);
}
```